# How to program these structures?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I have three objects, which (at the moment) I am representing as structs:

- a `Dataset`
- a `DatasetWindow`
- a `MovingWindow`

and a variable `windowSize`

There may be multiple `Dataset`'s and each should have it's own `DatasetWindow`. 
Ok, fair enough, to me that sounds like I make a `DatasetWindow` struct and put it as a member of a `Dataset` struct

There would be just one `MovingWindow`, but it should know about all the `Dataset`'s.
Ok, so far it seems pretty simple. I create another struct for `MovingWindow` and it has a pointer to `Dataset`. (an array of datasets).

So so far, I have something like this:

```
typedef struct {
      int *buffer;
      int someOtherMember;
      } DatasetWindow;

typedef struct {
      int someMember;
      DatasetWindow *window; //Pointer to a DatasetWindow obj.
      } Dataset;

typedef struct {
      int offset;
      int someMember;
      Dataset *datasets; //Array of Dataset
      } MovingWindow;
```

The part I am having trouble with is this:
`MovingWindow` should know `windowSize`, as should each `DatasetWindow`.
But `Dataset` should preferably not need to know what `windowSize` is.

I don't know how to arrange my structures to support this?

Comment: Add a pointer to windowSize in the structures?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the definitions of structs `MovingWindow` and `DatasetWindow` to incorporate a member (pointer or a interger variable) holding the value of your `windowSize`.